# How to convert phoneGap project to Corodova iOS project in for xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap

I'm new to cordova and I have an old ios project with phoneGap in vscode and now I don't know how to import it to cordova project in xcode.

cordova doesn't recognized the project as a cordova project when I copy the project folder to mac.

Answer (score 0):

create a new project, add all necessary platforms/plugins, and copy the www folder.